Getting errors while updating Angular build to esbuild
Updated the angular.json to use esbuild but getting these errors while building the app:
✘ [ERROR] Could not resolve "util"

    (disabled):node_modules/broadcast-channel/src/methods/node.js:6:21:
      6 │ const util = require('util');
        ╵                      ~~~~~~

  The package "util" wasn't found on the file system but is built into node. Are you trying to bundle for node? You can use "platform: 'node'" to do that, which will remove this error.


✘ [ERROR] Could not resolve "fs"

    (disabled):node_modules/broadcast-channel/src/methods/node.js:7:19:
      7 │ const fs = require('fs');
        ╵                    ~~~~

  The package "fs" wasn't found on the file system but is built into node. Are you trying to bundle for node? You can use "platform: 'node'" to do that, which will remove this error.

Here is the angular.json file:
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "reason-code": {
      "root": "projects/reason-code/",
      "sourceRoot": "projects/reason-code/src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "s2a",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser-esbuild",
          "options": {
            "allowedCommonJsDependencies": ["moment-timezone", "debug"],
            "assets": [
              {
                "glob": "favicon.ico",
                "input": "src/",
                "output": "/"
              },
              "projects/reason-code/src/assets"
            ],
            "budgets": [
              {
                "maximumError": "40mb",
                "maximumWarning": "35mb",
                "type": "initial"
              },
              {
                "maximumError": "18kb",
                "maximumWarning": "12kb",
                "type": "anyComponentStyle"
              }
            ],
            "buildOptimizer": false,
            "index": "projects/reason-code/src/index.html",
            "main": "projects/reason-code/src/main.ts",
            "namedChunks": true,
            "optimization": false,
            "outputHashing": "all",
            "outputPath": "dist/reason-code",
            "polyfills": "projects/reason-code/src/polyfills.ts",
            "preserveSymlinks": true,
            "progress": true,
            "scripts": ["tmp/localStorage.js"],
            "sourceMap": {
              "styles": true,
              "scripts": true,
              "vendor": false
            },
            "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": ["node_modules", "projects/reason-code/src/app/app-component-styles"]
            },
            "styles": ["projects/reason-code/src/styles.scss"],
            "tsConfig": "projects/reason-code/tsconfig.app.json",
            "vendorChunk": true,
            "watch": true
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "watch": false,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "projects/reason-code/src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "projects/reason-code/src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "baseHref": "/reason-code/",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "progress": false,
              "aot": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "scripts": []
            },
            "production-flash": {
              "watch": false,
              "assets": [],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "projects/reason-code/src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "projects/reason-code/src/environments/environment.flash.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputPath": "dist/reason-code-flash",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "progress": false,
              "aot": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "scripts": [],
              "styles": [],
              "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
                "includePaths": ["node_modules", "projects/reason-code/src/app/app-component-styles-flash"]
              },
              "deployUrl": "auto"
            },
            "development": {
              "watch": false,
              "scripts": [],
              "baseHref": "/reason-code/"
            },
            "development-local-flash": {
              "watch": false,
              "assets": [],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "projects/reason-code/src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "projects/reason-code/src/environments/environment.flash.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputPath": "dist/reason-code-flash",
              "scripts": ["tmp/localStorage.js", "scripts/flash/s2aWindow.js"],
              "styles": [],
              "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
                "includePaths": ["node_modules", "projects/reason-code/src/app/app-component-styles-flash"]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "reason-code:build",
            "watch": true,
            "port": 4201
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "reason-code:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "reason-code:build:development",
              "port": 4201
            },
            "development-local-flash": {
              "browserTarget": "reason-code:build:development-local-flash",
              "port": 4201
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "reason-code:build"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-eslint/builder:lint",
          "options": {
            "lintFilePatterns": ["projects/reason-code/**/*.ts", "projects/reason-code/**/*.html"]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false,
    "schematicCollections": ["@angular-eslint/schematics"]
  },
  "schematics": {
    "@angular-eslint/schematics:application": {
      "setParserOptionsProject": true
    },
    "@angular-eslint/schematics:library": {
      "setParserOptionsProject": true
    }
  }
}

